# Prove that for $f(x) = \frac{x^\textrm{T}Ax}{x^\textrm{T}x}$ and any $v$, $v^\textrm{T}Hv=0$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-calculus, hessian-matrix

$f(x) = \frac{x^\textrm{T}Ax} {x^\textrm{T}x}$, where $A$ is a symmetric $n \times n$ matrix and $x \neq 0$. I need to prove that if $H=H(f)(v)$, where $H(f)(v)$ is the Hessian of function $f$ evaluated for vector $v$, $v^\textrm{T}Hv=0$ for any $v$.

I have already proved that:

(a) $\frac{df}{dx}=0$ iff $x$ is an eigenvector of $A$;

(b) $f(cx) = f(x)$ for $c \in R$;

(c) $\lambda_\min \leq f \leq \lambda_\max$ where $\lambda_\max$ and $\lambda_\min$ are the maximal and minimal eigenvalues of $A$.

The hint to the question states the following: “ Hint: do not attempt to calculate the Hessian directly: the algebra is very messy. Use
the intuition gave by (b), that a certain function is constant.”

Comment: What is $H$? What is the meaning of $H(f)(v)$? What does the equation $H=H(f)(v)$ mean? Is $H$ a matrix, or a function/operator of $f$, or a function of $v$?

Comment: @Michael: sorry, should have clarified in the statement that $H$ is the Hessian matrix.

Comment: Since $A$ has an orthogonal basis of eigenvectors $y_1, ..., y_n$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_n$ then you can write $x = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i y_i$ where the coefficients $(a_1, ..., a_n)$ are a linear function of $(x_1, ..., x_n)$.

Comment: The Hessian of $f$ should be $H=H(f)$ instead of $H(f)(v)$. You want to show that $v^THv=$ for any $v\in R^n$. Am I right?

Comment: @xpaul: yes, that’s what I want to show. Thanks.

Comment: I think it can be solved by using (b).

Comment: @xpaul: that’s what the hint says as well, but unfortunately I don’t see how. :(

Comment: Sorry, that’s assuming $x \neq 0$ and $c \neq 0$.

Comment: @Michael: I think your solution is the right one, but I can’t write it out unfortunately. Could you please write it out in more detail to show that the Hessian is always 0? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to use the hint.  Perhaps you have some expression involving the Hessian that can be used. Here is a brute-force approach that seems to work for any square matrix $A$ (regardless of symmetry): We have
$$ f(x) = \frac{x^{\top}Ax}{x^{\top}x} $$
Define $N(x)$ and $D(x)$ as numerator and denominator functions:
$$ N(x) = x^{\top}Ax, \quad D(x) = x^{\top}x$$
Then
$$ D(x) f(x) = x^{\top}Ax \quad  $$
Taking the gradient of both sides, expressing the gradient as a row vector, gives
$$ f(x) \nabla D(x)  + D(x) \nabla f(x)  = 2x^{\top}A \quad (*)$$
Now from derivative formulas we know $\nabla D(x) = 2x^{\top}$.
Substituting this into (*) gives
$$ 2f(x) x^{\top}  + D(x) \nabla f(x)  = 2x^{\top} A $$
Taking the derivative again gives
$$ 2(\nabla f(x))^{\top}x^{\top} + 2f(x) I + (\nabla D(x))^{\top} \nabla f(x) + D(x) H(x) = 2A$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix.
Substituting $\nabla D(x)=2x^{\top}$ gives
$$ 2(\nabla f(x))^{\top} x^{\top} + 2f(x) I + 2x \nabla f(x) + D(x) H(x) = 2A$$
Substituting $D(x)=x^{\top} x$, assuming $x \neq 0$, and rearranging terms gives
$$ \boxed{H(x) = 2\left(\frac{A  - f(x) I - x \nabla f(x) -  (\nabla f(x))^{\top}x^{\top}}{x^{\top} x}\right)}$$
Thus
\begin{align}
x^{\top} H(x)x &= 2\left(\frac{x^{\top}Ax  - f(x) x^{\top}x -x^{\top}x \nabla f(x)x -  x^{\top}(\nabla f(x))^{\top}x^{\top}x }{x^{\top} x}\right)\\
& = -2 \nabla f(x) x - 2 x^{\top} (\nabla f(x))^{\top}\\
&= -4 \nabla f(x) x
\end{align}

---

It remains to show $\nabla f(x) x=0$ for all $x \neq 0$.

$$ f(x) = \frac{N(x)}{D(x)}  $$
$$ \nabla f(x) = \frac{D(x)\nabla N(x) - N(x)\nabla D(x)}{D(x)^2} = \frac{D(x)2x^{\top}A - N(x) 2x^{\top}}{||x||^4}$$
$$ \nabla f(x) x = \frac{D(x)2x^{\top}Ax - N(x) 2x^{\top}x}{||x||^4}=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $v_1,v_2,\cdots, v_n$ be a basis of $R^n$ such that they are eigenvectors of $A$. By (a),
$$ \nabla f(x)v_i=\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial v_i}=0, \forall x\in R^n. $$
So
\begin{eqnarray}
v_j^TH(f)v_i=H(f)(v_i,v_j)=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\nabla f(x+tv_i)(v_j)-\nabla f(x)(v_j)}{t}=0.
\end{eqnarray}
Hence for $\forall v\in R^n$, $v=\sum_{i=1}^nc_iv_i$, one has
$$ vH(f)v=\sum_{i,j=1}^nc_ic_jv_j^HH(f)v_i=0. $$

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Could you please clarify why $ v_j^\textrm{T}H(f)v_i = H(f)(v_i, v_j) $ and what does $ H(f)(v_i,v_j) $ stand for?

Comment: This is the notation for Hessian. You can ignore it.

Comment: The first equation seems wrong, it is not true that $\nabla f(x) v_i = 0$ for all basis vectors $v_i$ and all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.  That would mean $\nabla f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @Michael, I will check. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\R}{\Bbb{R}}\newcommand{\x}{\mathbf{x}}\newcommand{\a}{\mathbf{a}}\newcommand{\y}{\mathbf{y}}\newcommand{\v}{\mathbf{v}}$You can do this by using some facts from multivariable calculus.

Fix $\v \in \R^n$. Let $\phi:\R \to \R$ be defined by $\phi(c)=f(c\v)$. By part (b), we know that $\phi$ is constant, so $\phi'(c)=0$ and $\phi''(c)=0$ for all $c\in \R$.

The result will now follow by doing some multivariable calculus computations to show that in fact $\phi''(c) = \v^T (H(f)(c\v))\v$ (then putting $c=1$).

Firstly, note that
$$\begin{align*}
\phi'(c) &= D_c (f(c\v))\\
&= \v^T \nabla f(c\v) \quad (\text{using fact 1 from the bottom})
\end{align*}
$$

where $\nabla f(\x)$ is the gradient vector of $f$ evaluated at $\x$ and is expressed as a column vector.

Therefore, we have

$$\begin{align*}
\phi''(c) &= D_c (\v^T \nabla f(c\v))  \\
&= \v^T \left( D_c  \nabla f(c\v)\right) \quad (\text{using fact 2 from the bottom})\\
&= \v^T \left( (H(f)(c\v)) \v\right) \quad (\text{ using fact 3 and multivariable  chain rule}) \\
&= \v^T (H(f)(c\v)) \v.
\end{align*}
$$

Put $c=1$ and recall that $\phi''(1)=0$ to get the desired result.

---

A summary of the multivariable calculus facts used is given below.

If $h:\R^{n}\to\R^{m}$, then denote by $D_{\x} (h)$ ("the Jacobian of $h$") the $m\times n$ matrix whose $i,j$ entry is equal to $\dfrac{\partial h_i}{\partial x_j}$ for $i=1,\ldots,m$ and $j=1,\ldots,n$. (Here $h(\x) = \begin{bmatrix} h_1(\x) \\ \vdots \\ h_m(\x)\end{bmatrix}$ where $h_i:\R^n \to \R$ are the components of $h$ and $\x =  \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n\end{bmatrix} \in \R^n$.) If we evaluate the Jacobian at a point $\a\in \R^n$, we may denote this as $D_{\x} (h)(\a)$ or $D_{\x} (h(\a))$.

The multivariable chain rule tells us that if $h:\R^{n}\to\R^{m}$ and $g: \R^{p}\to\R^{n}$, with the composite function $h\circ g : \R^p \to \R^m$, denoting $\y = g(\x)$ where $\x\in \R^n$ and $\y\in\R^p$, we have $D_{\x}(h\circ g) = (D_{\y} h)(D_{\x} g)$ (matrix product). Note in this formula, if $D_{\x}(h\circ g)$ is evaluated at $\a\in \R^p$, then $D_{\y} h$ should be evaluated at $\mathbf{b} = g(\a)\in \R^n$ and $D_{\x} g$ should be evaluated at $\a\in\R^p$.

I leave as an exercise to you to show the following facts (with some hints), which were used in some form above:

> Fact 1. Let $f:\R^n\to \R$ and $\v$ a fixed vector in $\R^n$. Let $\phi:\R\to \R, \quad \phi(c)=f(c\v)$. Then $(D_c \phi) (c)\equiv \phi'(c) = \v^T \nabla f(c\v)$, where $\nabla f(c\v)$ is the gradient vector of $f$ evaluated at $c\v$. (Use multivariable chain rule to show this.)

> Fact 2. (Derivative can "move inside" product with fixed matrix) Let $h:\R^n\to \R^m$ and $B$ be a fixed $p\times m$ matrix. Let $g:\R^n \to \R^p$ be given by $g(\x) =  B h(\x)$ for $\x\in \R^n$. Then $D_{\x} g = B \left(D_{\x} h\right)$. (You can show this very easily using the multivariable chain rule.)

> Fact 3. (Hessian of a function is equal to Jacobian of gradient) Let $f:\R^n\to \R$ be a twice continuously differentiable function. Then $H(f)(\x) = D_{\x}(\nabla f(\x))$ for all $\x\in \R^n$.

Comment: $\newcommand{\v}{\mathbf{v}}\newcommand{\x}{\mathbf{x}}$When I write $\nabla f(c\v)$, I mean the gradient of $f$ evaluated at $c\v$. The "gradient of $f$" here is just with respect to the variables of $f$. As a simple example (consider $n=2$ with $\x =(x_1,x_2)^T$ and $\v = (v_1,v_2)^T$), if $f(\x)=x_1^2+ x_2$, then the gradient of $f$ is $\nabla f(\x) = \left( 2x_1, 1\right)^T$, so $\nabla f(c\v)$ just means plug $\x = c\v$ into this, i.e. $\nabla f(c\v ) =  \left( 2cv_1, 1\right)^T$. Similar story with the Hessian (i.e. $H(f)(c\v)$ means the Hessian of $f$ evaluated at the point $c\v$).

Comment: @Marcus: great, many thanks for the clarification. So $\triangledown f(cv)$ is equivalent to $\frac{df}{dx}(cv)$ where $cv$ is some vector similar to $x$? And then why do we need $_C$ in the notation for the Jacobian $D_C$?

Comment: $\newcommand{\v}{\mathbf{v}}\newcommand{\x}{\mathbf{x}}$$\nabla f(c\v)$ is the *gradient $\nabla f(\x)$ evaluated at $\x = c\v$*. To take a simple single variable example, suppose $f(x) = x^2$ for $x\in \Bbb{R}$. Then $\nabla f \equiv f'$, so $\nabla f(cv) \equiv f'(cv) = 2cv$ for $c,v\in \Bbb{R}$. (Because $\nabla f(x) \equiv f'(x)=2x$, so $\nabla f(cv) \equiv f'(cv) = 2cv$. So we just took the derivative (or gradient) $f'(x)$, and evaluated it at $x=cv$.)

Comment: $\newcommand{\v}{\mathbf{v}}\newcommand{\x}{\mathbf{x}}$When doing the Jacobian $D_c$, that means I am differentiating **with respect to $c$**. This is different to $\nabla f(c\v)$, which refers to taking the gradient of $f(\x)$ with respect to $\x$ and then evaluating this gradient at the point $\x = c\v$. As a single variable example again, suppose $f(x)=x^2$ for $x\in \Bbb{R}$ and let $v$ be a fixed real number. Then $D_c(f(cv))$ means $\frac{d}{dc}(f(cv))$, whereas $\nabla f(cv)$ means $f'(cv)$. So make sure you are clear on the difference between $\frac{d}{dc}(f(cv))$ and $f'(cv)$.

Comment: One-Twelth: but then in the last line of your proof $D_{C}(\triangledown f(cv))$ = $D_{C}(\frac{df}{dx}(cv))$, but that is not equal to $H(f)(cv) = D_{X}(\frac{df}{dx}(cv))$=$D_{X}(\triangledown f(cv))$. Sorry for all those questions? Maybe it's just that I'm a bit confused with the notation, and it would be simpler if everything was written in the $\frac{df}{dx}$ notation.

Comment: $\newcommand{\v}{\mathbf{v}}\newcommand{\n}{\nabla}$$D_{c}(\n f(c\v))$ is equal to $H(f)(c\v)\color{blue}{\v}$, that is, the Hessian of $f$ at $c\v$ is *multiplied by $\v$*. If you look closely, I had put a $\v$ after the $H(f)(c\v)$ in my answer.